# Challenge : if panel is click close unnecessary slides

Tags: jquery, menu

When I click a slide I want to make jQuery check if another slide is open and close it. I've written 90% of the code, but something is missing. See my HTML below:

Here is my  [challenge](http://jsfiddle.net/Code_me/DDSu2/)!

```
//first slide
$('#one').toggle(function(){
$('.content').animate({width:'42%'});
}, function(){ 
$('.content').animate({width:'0%'}); 
});

//second slide
$('#two').toggle(function(){
$('.content1').animate({width:'42%'});
}, function(){ 
$('.content1').animate({width:'0%'});
});

//the condition ,here is the chalenge
$(function(){
$('#two').click(function(){
var two = $('.content').innerWidth();
    //when the users click the second slide i want that jquery checks if another panel           is open(in my case .content) and close it :D
});


 });
```

Comment: why are you using different classes for every li?

Comment: I wouldn't base that decision on the actual width of any element - but rather set a status variable that holds the info which slide is currently open.

Comment: Side note: [.toggle(function, function, ... ) removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to separate function from style and using a generic solution, so you're able to expand it for example by adding a third slide.

HTML:

```
<ul id="vertical">
   <li class="js_slide"></li>
   <li class="content js_content"></li>
   <li class="js_slide"></li>
   <li class="content js_content"></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(".js_slide").click( function() {
    var $contentBlock = $(this).next(".js_content");

    if ( $contentBlock.hasClass("is_open") ) {
        $contentBlock.animate({width:'0%'}).removeClass("is_open");
    } else {
        // if a content box is open (=> an element with the class .is_open exists), close it
        $(".js_content.is_open").animate({width:'0%'}).removeClass("is_open");
        $contentBlock.animate({width:'42%'}).addClass("is_open");
    }

});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/rdequ/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could just go for this:

```
$('#one').toggle(function(){
                    $(".content1").animate({width:'0%'});
                    $('.content').animate({width:'42%'});
                }, 
                function(){ 
                     $('.content').animate({width:'0%'});
                });

$('#two').toggle(function(){
                    $(".content").animate({width:'0%'});
                    $('.content1').animate({width:'42%'});
                 }, 
                 function(){
                     $('.content1').animate({width:'0%'});
                 });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick...

Use a general class for your contents, and add an extra class that makes the content 'unique'

```
$('.one').toggle(function(){
  $('.content').stop().animate({{width:0});
  $('.content.one').stop().animate({width:'42%'});
}, function(){ 
  $('.content').animate({width:'0%'}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this? With a slight change in htmL YOU CAN ACHEIVE THIS..

HTML:

```
<ul id="vertical">
    <li class="one"></li>
    <li class="content"></li>
    <li class="one"></li>
    <li class="content"></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
//first slide
$('.one').toggle(function () {
    $(this).next().animate({
        width: '42%'
    });
    $(this).next().siblings('.content').not($(this).next()).animate({
        width: '0%'
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).next().animate({
        width: '0%'
    });
    $(this).next().siblings('.content').not($(this).next()).animate({
        width: '0%'
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/writetobhuwan/DDSu2/1/

Comment: I find your example verry useful :D